# Eclipse galieo does not show classes directory inside build

Tags: eclipse, servlets

Due to this problem, a servlet does not execute on it.  What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try Navigator view (Window -> Show View -> Navigator). Some F5 (refresh) hits may help too.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that that a filter hides those files. Go to your package explorer window, then use the pull-down menu icon, most right one, then check 'Filters...'.